# DocuSign Deep Integration for Android

Tags: android, android-webview, digital-signature, docusignapi

I'm trying to integrate DocuSign into my Android App to manage digital signatures. I've tried some of the sample code and read the documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign).

It seems that I have to use a WebView for the signing process.

Are there any libraries or any part of the SDK that I'm missing that will allow me to use native android views (other than a WebView) or custom views so I can preserve the look and feel of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no. The "signing ceremony" itself is supplied by DocuSign via a webview.

The good news is that you can "brand" many aspects of the signing ceremony so that the colors, text, and other aspects can be more inline with your app.

See the branding guides:

- https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding
- https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/New%20Signing%20Experience%20Information%20Guide_0.pdf

Comment: I accepted the answer, but are native integration capabilities available on higher plans?